# Creating landscapes of different shapes in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

Currently the landscape I setup in NetLogo includes patches of "typrAgro" in a strip on top and "typeTrop" in a block along the bottom.

```
to setup
ca
clear-all-plots
clear-output

set typeAgro 1  ;where people will be located
set typeTrop 2  ;where animals will be located
ask patches
[ set habitat typeAgro ]
ask patches with [pycor <= 500] ;world is 600 x 600 pixels
[ set habitat typeTrop]

set AgroForst patches with [ is-Agro? ]
set TropForst patches with [ is-Trop? ]

ask AgroForst
[ set pcolor 75 ]

ask TropForst
[ set pcolor 65 ]

reset-ticks                              

end
```

Instead I'd like to create landscapes that have several generic shapes, for example, like those in the image below.  In particular, I have no idea how to create the last two shapes (a long linear shape and the random polygon).  Any suggestions on how to get started on that would really help. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The rotated ellipse will take some math. Googling "tilted ellipse" or "rotated ellipse" will turn up some sources, then you just need to translate the math into NetLogo. I don't recall ever seeing NetLogo code for this. As for the blob, you want to draw that with the mouse, or what? What characterizes the shape you're trying to produce?

Comment: The only criterion I have for the blob right now is that it have the same area as the other shapes.  I suppose I could draw with the mouse but I don't know how to ensure equal area that way.  The idea is to explore how shape mediates the impact of human agents (outside shape) on animal agents (inside shape).  I'm starting with a set of basic shapes.  I could replace the random blob with something else more mathematically tractable if that makes more sense.

Comment: Can you ask a separate question about generating random blobs of a given area? I think it's interesting problem in itself.

Comment: Sure.  I just posted it.

Answer (score 2):

One way I would suggest is creating your map using paint or anything else and define your regions using different colors and then import is as background. 
Using

```
 import-pcolors  "test.png"
```

In your setup procedures you can ask different patches with different colors to set their arguments based on your model requirements.

[image]